# Weird animation behaviour of AnimatedContainer when wrapped in IntrinsicHeight

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have created a container in which two AnimatedContainers are located. When i press the down button i would like the TextFieldContainer (The content with the white TextField in the middle) to disappear by decreasing it size to 0. Simountanesly i want to make the ToolbarContainer appear by increasing its size. So far this is what i get:

[image: Animation Behaviour]

It looks like only one of the AnimatedContainers can animate its properties one at a time, which creates the werid behaviour as shown, where one of the AnimatedContainers animate quickly, then slowly and then quickly once again.

How do i make the animation smooth so the overall size of the main container does not change because the two AnimatedContainers animate their size equally quick and simountanesly?

Here is the code for the main container:

```
class _MessageToolbarContainerState extends State<MessageToolbarContainer> {
  bool toggleToolbar = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: widget.availableWidth - 75,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 25.0),
      constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: 50.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.blue,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)),
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.grey,
          width: 2.0,
        ),
      ),
      child: Material(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)),
        elevation: 5.0,
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            AnimatedContainer(
              duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                minHeight: toggleToolbar ? 0.0 : 50.0,
                maxHeight: toggleToolbar ? 0.0 : 100.0,
              ),
              child: IntrinsicHeight(
                child: TextFieldContent(
                  onDownPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      toggleToolbar = !toggleToolbar;
                      print(toggleToolbar);
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            AnimatedContainer(
              duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                minHeight: !toggleToolbar ? 0.0 : 50.0,
                maxHeight: !toggleToolbar ? 0.0 : 100.0,
              ),
              child: IntrinsicHeight(
                child: ToolbarContent(
                  onUpPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      toggleToolbar = !toggleToolbar;
                      print(toggleToolbar);
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I have boiled the problem down to one widget. I have wraped my AnimatedContainers in two IntrinsicHeight widgets to keep their content from expanding to much. If i remove the IntrinsicHeight widgets i get the following output:

[image: New animation]

As it is clearly shown the AnimatedContainers now animate smoothly. Sadly that does not fix my problem. I added the IntrinsicHeight widgets to make the content expand as the user typed in the TextField. If i remove the IntrinsicHeight widgets the content of the AnimatedContainers are not displayed properly.

The original question still stands. How do I make the 2 AnimatedContainers animate properly when they are wrapped in an IntrinsicHeight widget?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue when I run your code in my emulator the transition is smooth. Maybe the issue comes from outside this code.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @wcyankees424
See the edit of the question. Maybe you can reproduce it now